# terminal server, hide desktop icons doesn't work as expected

Tags: group-policy, terminal-server

In the User part of a GPO that i activate for users who log on a terminal server, i tried to set the Administrative Templates, Desktop, "Hide and disable all objects on the desktop" (may be that the name isn't exact because i've translated it from italian, unfortunately).
Since the guide (also in italian) points out clearly that this gpo will hide also "My network places", i expect it to do so, and to disappear from Explorer too. 
Well it doesn't, while it disappears if i set the network-places dedicated gpo, just a few lines below.
Is this a bug or the guide should be interpreted in another way?

Answer (score 1):

From the Description for each of the GPO settings you referenced:

> Hide and disable all items on the desktop:
>
> Removes icons, shortcuts, and other default and user-defined items
>   from the desktop, including Briefcase, Recycle Bin, Computer, and
>   Network Locations.
>
> Removing icons and shortcuts does not prevent the user from using
>   another method to start the programs or opening the items they
>   represent.
>
> Also, see "Items displayed in Places Bar" in User
>   Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Common Open
>   File Dialog to remove the Desktop icon from the Places Bar. This will
>   help prevent users from saving data to the Desktop.

---

> Hide Network Locations icon on desktop:
>
> Removes the Network Locations icon from the desktop.
>
> This setting only affects the desktop icon. It does not prevent users
>   from connecting to the network or browsing for shared computers on the
>   network.
>
> Note: In operating systems earlier than Microsoft Windows Vista, this
>   policy applies to the My Network Places icon.

In neither case does it say that it disables the ability to see and browse the network from Windows Explorer. What are you trying to accomplish?